# How to set a conditional newline in PS1?

Tags: bash, shell, ps1

I am trying to set `PS1` so that it prints out something just right after login, but preceded with a newline later.

Suppose `export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ "`, so first time (i.e., right after login) you get:

```
hostname:~ username$
```

I’ve been trying something like in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
function __ps1_newline_login {
  if [[ -n "${PS1_NEWLINE_LOGIN-}" ]]; then
    PS1_NEWLINE_LOGIN=true
  else
    printf '\n'
  fi
}

export PS1="\$(__ps1_newline_login)\h:\W \u\$ “
```

expecting to get:

```
# <empty line>
hostname:~ username$
```

A complete example from the the beginning would be:

```
hostname:~ username$ ls `# notice: no empty line desired above!`
Desktop      Documents

hostname:~ username$
```

Comment: For reference, the reason why your command doesn't work is 1) that you used double quotes, and therefore __ps1_newline_login runs when you do the export rather than every prompt, and 2) that if you had used single quotes, the function would have run in a subshell due to the $(..) so any variables you set would not be visible outside it

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you very much for this explanation. It really helped me understanding various issues of mine.

Comment: @thatotherguy thinking about this again: are you absolutely sure that `__ps1_newline_login` runs only–once, but not every time? For example `__git_ps1` uses this exact same technique to set every prompt not just initially.

Comment: Are you sure it uses `"$(__git_ps1)"` and not `'$(__git_ps1)'`? The quotes make all the difference. If it actually does use double quotes, it would have to `echo '$(foo)'` in order to place a literal string `'$(foo)'` in the prompt, which can then be subsequently expanded.

Comment: Yes, I am positive. It uses `$(__git_ps1)` with double quotes, and it seems to be working...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function __ps1_newline_login {
  if [[ -z "${PS1_NEWLINE_LOGIN}" ]]; then
    PS1_NEWLINE_LOGIN=true
  else
    printf '\n'
  fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='__ps1_newline_login'
export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ "
```

Explanation:

- `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a special bash variable which is executed every time before the prompt is set.
- You need to use the `-z` flag to check if the length of a string is 0.

Comment: further drilling on this subject: are you implying there is no way echoing/printing a newline from a function and using this in `PS1` as if you’d set it containing a `\n` in the first place?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get your question, but if you want the `\n` in `PS1`, you could simply update `PS1` and unset `PROMP_COMMAND` instead of `printf "'\n"`

Comment: This interferes with PROMPT_COMMAND updating the tab name to the current working directory. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 5):

Running with dogbane's answer, you can make PROMPT_COMMAND "self-destruct", preventing the need to run a function after every command.

In your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file, do

```
export PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
reset_prompt () {
  PS1='\n\h:\W \u\$ '
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='(( PROMPT_CTR-- < 0 )) && { 
  unset PROMPT_COMMAND PROMPT_CTR
  reset_prompt
}'
```

When the file is processed, `PS1` initially does not display a new-line before the prompt. 
However, `PROMPT_CTR` is immediately decremented to -1 (it is implicitly 0 before) before the prompt is shown the first time. After the first command, `PROMPT_COMMAND` clears itself and the counter before resetting the prompt to include the new-line. Subsequently, no `PROMPT_COMMAND` will execute.

Of course, there is a happy medium, where instead of `PROMPT_COMMAND` clearing itself, it just resets to a more ordinary function. Something like

```
export PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
normal_prompt_cmd () {
   ...
}
reset_prompt () {
  PS1='\n\h:\W \u\$ '
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='(( PROMPT_CTR-- < 0 )) && {
   PROMPT_COMMAND=normal_prompt_cmd
   reset_prompt
   unset PROMPT_CTR
  }'
```

Comment: How do you `reset_prompt` in the second form please? I may have been confused a little, I must admit.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The key thing to note is that you can change the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` inside `PROMPT_COMMAND`; it's not really recursion, since `PROMPT_COMMAND` is just a string that contains a mini-script to execute. One of the things that script could do is change the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: why not simply `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND}__ps1_newline_login;"`?

Comment: You could do that, but then you are executing the conditional check before *every* prompt. Modifying `PROMPT_COMMAND` gets rid of the check after you know that it is no longer necessary. (Granted, it's an extremely minor optimization that you will probably never notice in practice. This technique is more useful for shedding more expensive checks that you might make.)

Comment: This interferes with PROMPT_COMMAND updating the tab name to the current working directory. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 Update** (inspired by chepner's answer)

**UPDATE**:  Fixed `PROMPT_COMMAND` issues caused by other answers

Changes:

1. [No need to export PS1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247585/to-export-or-not-to-export-bash-ps1-variable)
2. I used "\n$PS1" instead of re-typing.
3. Other answers interfere with the `PROMPT_COMMAND`'s default behavior (more info below)

---

Enter the following in ~/.bash_profile (substituting first line with your prompt):

```
PS1=YOUR_PROMPT_HERE

add_newline_to_prompt() {
  is_new_login="true"
  INIT_PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"
  DEFAULT_PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
  PROMPT_COMMAND='{
    if [ $is_new_login = "true" ]; then
      is_new_login="false"
      eval $INIT_PROMPT_COMMAND
    else
      PS1="\n$PS1"
      PROMPT_COMMAND=$DEFAULT_PROMPT_COMMAND
    fi
  }'
}

add_newline_to_prompt
```

---

**PROMPT_COMMAND**

I noticed that my tab name in terminal wasn't updating to my current working directory and did some investigating. I realized that above solutions are messing with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Try this out:

1. Comment out any modifications to `PROMPT_COMMAND` in your config files (.bash_profile etc.)
2. Add `INIT_PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"` to your config file

Now open a new shell:

```
$ echo $INIT_PROMPT_COMMAND
shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
update_terminal_cwd
```

Notice that when you open a new shell, it runs both a "history check" and updates the name of the tab current working directory. Notice that it only runs the "history check" initially, and then never runs it again.

NOTE: I've only tested this on Mac's Terminal. May be different on other systems.

Comment: I like this! 

Comment: @Ali made an update (PROMPT_COMMAND) which you may be interested in

Comment: Thank you @JBallin

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your .bashrc:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="export PROMPT_COMMAND=echo"
alias clear="clear; export PROMPT_COMMAND='export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo''"
```

This achieves exactly what you want. No need for \n in PS1 or any functions.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! It seems to be working. Would you care to explain _how_ is it working though?