# Add newline after output of every bash command

Tags: bash, dotfiles

I'm in the process of customizing my terminal.

Currently, I have the following:

[image: before]

What I want is a newline after the output of every command, like this:

[image: after]

The only way I have been able to accomplish something close to this is by adding a newline at the *beginning* of my `PS1`. This works, but it annoys the hell out of me that the first time I open up a bash prompt, there is a newline above the very first line. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: `there is a newline above the very first line` Is that such a big problem?

Comment: Not really, just curious if there is a better way. It rubs my OCD the wrong way :(

Comment: Actually putting a newline above the very first line probably *is* the best way – super cheap and easy to understand.

Comment: @bitpshr Can I see your bashrc that gets you that format? I'd like to use it (I don't mind the newline when I first open the terminal)

Comment: I'm here trying to do the opposite and remove the newline

Comment: AHA! I bet it's the `PS1` mucking about

Answer (score 15):

One approach using `printf`:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' * $'\n'
```

or better (for every command):

```sh
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
$ ls
```

From [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) :

> If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set and has a non-null value, then the value is executed just as if it had been typed on the command line.

Comment: I like this method, but this is interpreted before `PS1` and still prints a newline above the very first line of the bash prompt, essentially equivalent to a newline at the beginning of `PS1`. I may be doing something wrong...

Comment: I'm really not sure how this is different from putting a newline at the beginning of PS1, which what OP asked not to do. (Except PROMPT_COMMAND is slightly more expensive.)

Comment: I once [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14860632/1126841) showing how to define `PRMOPT_COMMAND` in such a way that it redefines itself the first time it is called. You could adapt that so that `echo` is *not* called the very first time it is used in the shell, but is for each subsequent use.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work after every line of *output* instead of every command?

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND="export PROMPT_COMMAND=echo"` seems to work

Comment: For anyone who tries to get this to work in macOS: neither of these worked in zsh on macOS.

Answer (score 5):

Combining @GillesQuenot's answer with @chepner's comment this seems to work and it's quite simple:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="export PROMPT_COMMAND=echo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding up @GillesQuenot's answer + @chepner's comment with a neat hack for the `clear` command:

```
# Print newline AFTER executing a command
PROMPT_COMMAND="export PROMPT_COMMAND=echo"
alias clear="unset PROMPT_COMMAND; clear; PROMPT_COMMAND='export PROMPT_COMMAND=echo'"
```